# Show that for any fixed integer $n\geq1$, the sequence $2,2^2,{2^{2}}^{2},{{2^2}^2}^2,...(\mod n)$ is eventually constant

Tags: number-theory

I was going through a proof for the following statement, but I'm having trouble understanding it:

> Show that for any fixed integer $n\geq1$, the sequence $2,2^2,{2^{2}}^{2},{{2^2}^2}^2,...(\mod n)$ is eventually constant

**Proof:**

> Suppose the problem statement is false for some integer $n\geq1$. There is at least one $n$, which we call $b$ for which the statement is false. Since all integers are equivalent $\mod 1$, $b\neq 1$.
>
> Note that for all integers b, the sequence 2^0,2^1,2^2... eventually becomes cyclic \mod b

How can we prove that the sequence eventually becomes cyclic?

Let's assume $2^1 \equiv r \mod b$. Then $2^2 \equiv r^2\mod b$, $2^3 \equiv r^3 \mod b$ and so on, where $r>b$. Let's assume the period cycle to be $k$. If $r=1$, the proof becomes very easy since it will always be cyclic. If $r \neq 1$, we'll have to prove that $r^k \equiv r \mod b$. I don't know proceed further?

Comment: The sequence $x_n = 2^n \mod b$ becomes eventually cyclic because it has the form $x_{n+1} = 2 x_n$, that is to say $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$ and the set of remainders modulo $b$ is finite. However this alone does not solve the problem for the original sequence.

Comment: You can use induction. For odd $n>1$, to show $2^{2^{2^{2^{\dots}}}}$ becomes constant mod $n$, it suffices to show that $2^{2^{2^{\dots}}}$ becomes constant mod $\text{ord}_n(2)$, and note $\text{ord}_n(2) \in (1,n)$. And you can always assume $n$ is even by Chinese Remainder Theorem.